# Centos 6 vs Centos 7 file access performance

Tags: performance, centos6, centos7, strace, stat

I'd like some assistance in trying to figure out what could explain Centos 7 being slower in accessing a file then Centos 6. It's about a 17% difference.

Here's a simple test:

```
[root@test-centos6 shm]# time for i in $(seq 0 50000); do stat file > /dev/null; done

real    0m42.283s
user    0m2.465s
sys     0m4.434s
[root@test-centos6 shm]# time for i in $(seq 0 50000); do stat file > /dev/null; done

real    0m41.890s
user    0m2.442s
sys     0m4.341s
[root@test-centos6 shm]# time for i in $(seq 0 50000); do stat file > /dev/null; done

real    0m41.795s
user    0m2.383s
sys     0m4.310s

----

[root@test-centos7 shm]# time for i in $(seq 0 50000); do stat file > /dev/null; done

real    0m49.081s
user    0m16.306s
sys     0m32.639s
[root@test-centos7 shm]# time for i in $(seq 0 50000); do stat file > /dev/null; done

real    0m48.379s
user    0m16.034s
sys     0m32.191s
[root@test-centos7 shm]# time for i in $(seq 0 50000); do stat file > /dev/null; done

real    0m48.054s
user    0m15.680s
sys     0m32.245s
```

strace seems to confirm C7 performs more operations per stat then C6.

```
[root@test-centos6 shm]# strace stat file 2>&1 | wc -l
145

[root@test-centos7 shm]# strace stat file 2>&1 | wc -l
168
```

Anyone knows how to reduce the number of operations for C7 so perfs are more inline with C6?

Thank you,

//EDIT:

I have put both in /dev/shm to eliminate a possible xfs/ext4 difference.
These are 2 identical VMs on the same ESX host, with just a different OS. (but I have observed the same difference on hardware boxes as well, just used those VMs for my current testing)

Strace C6: https://paste.fedoraproject.org/paste/oCSUZqKgcoNLJubjeNbo9V5M1UNdIGYhyRLivL9gydE=
Strace C7: https://paste.fedoraproject.org/paste/PvTXvxxvS~2UZ9LuuSVAA15M1UNdIGYhyRLivL9gydE=

I would have assumed the newer C7 would have better performances in it's stock form, not worse.

```
[root@test-centos6 shm]# uname -r
2.6.32-642.el6.x86_64
[root@test-centos6 shm]# getenforce
Disabled

[root@test-centos7 shm]# uname -r
3.10.0-514.6.1.el7.x86_64
[root@test-centos7 shm]# getenforce
Disabled
```

Comment: What filesystems?  What hardware?

Comment: Looks like they are in /dev/shm (ramdisk) but it would be great to get confirmation.

Comment: I believe you may also wish to [upload your strace output](https://tinyvpn.org/) so people can take a peek.  Not all folks may have both C6 and C7 images active somewhere.

Comment: I've edited my question with answers.

Comment: Is SELinux configuration similar in both cases?

Comment: Selinux is fully disabled.

Comment: Is this even a realistic test? How much does your actual workload rely on repeated `stat()` calls?

Comment: Yes this is a realistic test as we heavily rely on file existence tests for this system (~ 90 million calls per day)

Comment: Does your application use stat via a shell builtin or the command line? It may have a lot less overhead written in a different language, maybe even C.

Answer (score 0):

They are totally different operating systems with different kernels, compiled-defaults, filesystems, schedulers and tuning capabilities.

Why do you assume they should perform alike? There's a lot to account for, so this question will be difficult to answer in its current form.

Comment: I have assumed that the newer C7 would have better performances, or at least on-par with it's predecessor, not worse. I'm now looking for how to tune it to perform better. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The `stat` utility differs between CentOS6 and CentOS7. To confirm, try issuing `stat --version` on both machines.

The new `strace` version is more complex, perhaps. For example, from your `strace` output, it appears that CentOS7's `strace` maps `libpcre.so.1` (a reguar expression library), while CentOS6's `strace` does not.

Anyway, this basically is a canned test: to really benchmark file access/manipulation speed, you should use tools as `fs_mark` or, even better, some real world test (eg: untar a large archive).